# Magento1: max_execution_time problem

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

For some reason we face a max_execution_time error of 60 seconds, when running some cronjobs.

Already checked php.ini file and both local and master value of max_execution_time are set to: 220000.

So that can not be the problem, but still we see the errors in the log files.

Does magento somewhere store the max_execution_time of 60 seconds (for cronjobs)?

See error in cron log:

```
[09-Aug-2018 05:35:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 135
[09-Aug-2018 07:09:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 1110
[09-Aug-2018 07:41:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php on line 549
```

Comment: did you check the php.ini for cli? there can be different values for max execution time for web and cli

Comment: check your memory_limit size and max_input_time increase these and test these are successfully set.

Comment: @Marius Yes, check that one, we use the same php.ini for cli.

Comment: @CharulTyagi Thanks! We now have memory_limit = 12288m; and max_input_time: -1. What do you recommend.

Comment: @Henk first check with increasing both max_execution_time and max_input_time and check with these if not work then check max_input_vars may be you have a lot of variables when cron request going.

Comment: @CharulTyagi Thanks! We still face this issue. See my edit, I placed the errors from our log. Can not find any max execution time of 60 sec on our server.

Comment: @HenkZ so how much values set on server for max_execution_time,max_input_time and max_input_vars ?

Comment: @CharulTyagi Just at one place, in the main php.ini file.